# Upgrade CakePHP 1.2 to 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, upgrade, cakephp-1.2

**What I have :**

I have cakephp application,which is in CakePHP 1.2.12.

**What I tried :**

I use Upgrade Plugin : https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-upgrade

I have followed all the step

1. I have download new Cakephp 2.4
2. I have create Plugin in folder inside app of cakephp1.3 application
3. rename /app/config folder to /app/Config
4. write CakePlugin::loadAll(); in my app/Config bootstrap

**What the error :**

when I try to

```
..\lib\Cake\Console\cake Upgrade.Upgrade all
```

Its give me error like

```
Error: Plugin Upgrade could not be found.
  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(365): CakePlugin::path('Upgrade')
  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(226): App::pluginPath('Upgrade')
  #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(547): App::path('Console/Command', 'Upgrade')
  #3 [internal function]: App::load('UpgradeShell')
  #4 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('UpgradeShell')
  #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(247): class_exists('UpgradeShell')       
   #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(198): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('Upgrade.Upgrade')
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
   #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp24\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php(49): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
   #9 {main}
```

Comment: Where did you put the plugin? In APP/Vendor/Upgrade as you are supposed to?

Comment: No, Upgrade plugin is in APP/Plugin/{ Plugin name }

Comment: @mark I made a folder Plugin inside APP, and I put Upgrade plugin in there

Comment: Make sure debug mode is on. Or clear the cache - so the plugin is properly loaded.

Comment: @mark: Yes, Already debug mode is 2. and Clear whole cache from tmp/cache

Comment: @mark : Am I on right track, or need to change otherthings ?

Comment: Why not 2.5=master? That is the current version you should be upgrading to :) But yeah you are on the right track. Just get the plugin/shell to work first. Where do you execute the command from? The app dir as documented?

Comment: yes I execute it from command line in windows.Yes The app dir as same as documented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58808/discussion-between-chetanspeed511987-and-mark).

Comment: @chetanspeed511987 were you able to upgrade succesfuly?